# $scope is not defined in newly generated html using ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am new to angular js. I am doing like when I click on an anchor then it will open a new modal using ajax and load that html into modal. lets elaborate using code below. i hope this will help.

**HTML View Code:**

```
<a ng-click="open_modal();">Click</a>
<div id="mytest" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
$scope.open_modal = function () {

     $scope.customName = "XYZ ABC";  
     $('#mytest').load('modalData.html').modal();
}
```

**modalData.html Code**

```
<div>
    My name is {{customName}}
</div>
```

But when modal is open then my view is just
 **My name is {{customName}}**

Comment: Upload your full angularjs coe

Comment: You're loading something using jQuery...? Well, yeah, it won't have any idea about Angular's scope and template interpolations. You'll need to use Angular methods to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it isn't a right way how to display special html in angular application. Please use ng-include. It's directive where you pass url to template (html file) you want to display. Angular will automatically load it from server using url you provide in src.

The proper way to load html in your case is:

```
<div ng-include='modalData.html'></div>
```

Looking forward - if you need to create jQuery modal from this DOM element, it's now a `directive` that should be separated from page `controller` and treated as a separate component:

```
<modal name="ctrl.custom_name"></modal>
```

And `modal` directive will contain:

```
app.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
             name: '@'
        },
        template: 'modalData.html', // template will be also loaded from server by $templateCache
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            setTimeout(function() { 
                $(element).modal();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

As you are using method `open_modal()` in your `controller`, directive should acquire `ng-if` to initialize only when you need to display it:

```
<modal name="ctrl.customName" ng-if="ctrl.isModalOpened"></modal>
```

as well as method should contain:

```
PageController.prototype.openModal = function () {
    this.customName = "XYZ ABC";  
    this.isModalOpened = true;
}
```

P.S. Use camel case in JavaScript. Define methods in controller's `prototype` instead of `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think

```
$('#mytest').load('modalData.html').modal();
```

would work inside a controller.

Would be helpful if you could share a jsfiddle for the same.

Comment: Its working. modal is opening but scope data not working here.

Answer (score 0):

have you inject the $scope to your controller ?

Comment: Yes injected in controller.